# How do I count the occurence of a word in an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am working on a project where I have to read the data from a file into my code, in the txt file I have columns of data, and I have managed to separate each column of data into an array with this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line = "";
    String date = "";
    ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("list.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line.split("\\s+");
            date.add(line.split("\\s+")[0]);
            System.out.println(line.split("\\s+")[0]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    }
```

This will output the first column of data from the "list.txt" file which is...

```
30-Nov-2016
06-Oct-2016
05-Feb-2016
04-Sep-2016
18-Apr-2016
09-Feb-2016
22-Oct-2016
20-Aug-2016
17-Dec-2016
25-Dec-2016
```

However, I want to count the occurrence of the word "Feb" so for example it will come up...

"The month February occurs: 2 times"

But I'm struggling to find the right code, could somebody please help me on this matter I've been trying for over 24 hours, any help will be greatly appreciated, I can't find any other questions that help me.

Comment: You could simply use a regular expression

Comment: What expression would that be?

Comment: are they comma separated or newline ?

Comment: They're a new line, I just put the commas in myself because I didn't know how to present it properly, I'll edit it now that someone has done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be using `split`

```
String month = "Feb";
int count = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
   String strDate = line.split("\\s+")[0]; // get first column, which has date
   String temp = strDate.split("\\-")[1]; // get Month from extracted date.
   if (month.equalsIgnoreCase(temp))
   {
      count++;
      // or store strDate into List for further process.
   }
}
System.out.println (count);// should print total occurrence of date with Feb month
```

**==Edited==**

Since, you are extracting date from each `line` using `line.split("\\s+")[0]`, which means actual string, which only contains date would be extract string.

Comment: Sorry just isn't working at all I'm afraid, thanks for the help Ravi :( it just keeps counting 0, it isn't detecting the Feb at all,

Comment: @jonlajoey what are you saying.. https://ideone.com/szzZmq it is working fine. are you sure `line` only has date ?? can you share the value of `line` in each iteration ?

Comment: basically this is my code https://ideone.com/Wdg98E and here is the txt file http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1515392705314.txt, right now it's displaying the first column of the txt file, all the dates, so I've captured that first column in an array, now I want to output how many contracts are in February, so match the word "feb" in that array is what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to get it to work. Hope this helps

Comment: @jonlajoey you didn't mentioned this, that you have many other data and you have already extract 1st column, which has date. So, obviously, you won't get count. And, that is the reason I asked the value of line in each iteration

Comment: Oh right I apologise Ravi, that's why I'm attempting to make separate arrays so I can get a count on each one of them, is there a way it's possible?

Comment: @jonlajoey I have updated my post with some details. Please have a look

Comment: I've implemented your code in, and sadly it isn't working, it always comes up 0 no matter what, I even changed the value of String month to a specific date instead of Feb just to test that its at least working somewhat and it still came out 0. https://ideone.com/0mbaEV Here is the code

Comment: @jonlajoey because, you running loop twice, that is again obvious, second loop will never run. remove or comment out the first loop.

Comment: thank you so much, is there anyway I can reward you for this? I really appreciate this I've been stuck on this for over a day it's been frying my brain.

Comment: @jonlajoey of course, you can upvote and click tick to accept answer

Comment: @jonlajoey please read this on how can you award someone asnwer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Yep just done that, you've been a great help, I'm new to Java and I've had this project laid on me in such short notice this really helps.

Comment: @jonlajoey you accepted and then reverted . anyway, it was your choice :)

Comment: Oops sorry, I tried to do both, I'll choose you, you went through a lot to help.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you could simply use a regular expression, something like...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Feb", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("30-Nov-2016, 06-Oct-2016, 05-Feb-2016, 04-Sep-2016, 18-Apr-2016, 09-Feb-2016, 22-Oct-2016, 20-Aug-2016, 17-Dec-2016, 25-Dec-2016");
int count = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Count = " + count);
```

Which, based on the input, would be `2`.

Now, obviously, if you're reading each value from a file one at a time, this is not that efficient, and simply using something like...

```
if (line.toLowerCase().concat("feb")) {
    count++;
}
```

would be simple and quicker

## Updated...

So, based on the provided input data and the following code...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Feb", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
int count = 0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("Data.txt")))) {
    String text = null;
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

It prints `67`.

Now, this is brute force method, because I'm checking the whole line. In order to overcome possible mismatches in the text, you should split the line by the common delimiter (ie tab character) and check the first element, for example...

```
String[] parts = text.split("\t");
Matcher m = p.matcher(parts[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you guys, just one question on the matcher. My list is only a sample, it has near 1000 dates, when I try to put the whole array with p.matcher for example p.matcher(date); I have a redline and it simply won't compute. I don't think there is any way I could possibly type in every single date for the matcher.

Comment: Well, assuming you’re loading the data from a file, you “could” use StringJoiner to build a string value or use the second example while reading each line

Comment: basically this is my code ideone.com/Wdg98E and here is the txt file m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1515392705314.txt, right now it's displaying the first column of the txt file, all the dates, so I've captured that first column in an array, now I want to output how many contracts are in February, so match the word "feb", however the code that you've given me will not match the userNames array (which I changed to date on here)

Comment: Thank you so much MadProgrammer this option also helps, I apologise for being awkward, I realise I didn't release enough information.